# Django Admin won't save TextFields as NULL, unlike CharFields

Tags: django-models, django-forms

```
    good_field = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, default=None, blank=True, unique=True)
    bad_field = models.TextField(null=True, default=None, blank=True, unique=True)
```

The good_field can be saved as blank and will end up as a NULL in the DB (which is important because of the `unique=True` but the bad_field gets saved as '' which violates the unique constraint.

Seems this was fixed for CharFields several years ago but for some reason not fixed for TextFields.  Is it possible to fix this for TextFields too or was their some architectural reason it was only fixed for CharFields.

I tried fixing it in the model, but the admin form is doing the unique testing (instead of letting the DB do that work) and my model level patching never gets a chance.

Is there a way to remove the unique validation from the admin form and let the DB do it's job?